# Python - 2 Arrays to 2 Columns + Random + Average

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, zip, multiple-columns

I have 2 arrays, some school subjects and 1 to 5 grades for those subjects. I need to take 4 random subjects from one array and 4 random numbers (grades) to each of those subjects and need to create columns:

```
import random
studentname = input("Write your name - ")
studentage = input("Write your age - ")
courses = ["English", "Mathematics", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Programming", "Biology", "Geography", "History"]
grades = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for line in zip(random.sample(courses,4), random.sample(grades,4), random.sample(grades,4), random.sample(grades,4), random.sample(grades,4)):
    print('{:15} {}  {}  {}  {} - Average = \n'.format(*line))
```

[image]

How do you add an average number for each of the subjects?

**Author Notes:**

I really searched everything, but didn't find anything even close, I found something using ZIP(), but i am new to Python, I could manage to create columns, but couldn't even add anything about average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop you could calculate the average of the input tuple (skipping the name of the course). Then add that argument to the format.

```
for line in zip(random.sample(courses,4),
                random.sample(grades,4),
                random.sample(grades,4),
                random.sample(grades,4), 
                random.sample(grades,4)):

    avg= sum(line[1:])/(len(line)-1)
    print('{:15} {}  {}  {}  {} - Average = \n {}'.format(*line,avg))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you just saved me.